# how to get field name inside value in Restful service?

Tags: java

I use this code below in our Restful service:(the type of output is json)

```
productList = new String[posList.size()][2];

for (int i = 0; i < posList.size(); i++) {  
     productList[i][0] =( posList.get(i).getUnitprice());
     productList[i][1] = (posList.get(i).getCategories().getCategoryName());
}
```

the results is this:

```
"item" : [
                "85000",

                "modem",
         ]
```

I want to get fieldname before it's value
how I can do this?

Comment: The question is unclear. What exactly should the JSON look like?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would simply be

```
for (int i = 0; i < posList.size(); i++) {  
     productList[i][1] =( posList.get(i).getUnitprice());
     productList[i][0] = (posList.get(i).getCategories().getCategoryName());
}
```

Or did I missunderstand what you wanted?

Comment: we have two tables: categories & products that "unitprice" field is in products & "categoryname" is in categories table.

Comment: my question purpose is this:                                                                     I want to get standard  json service like: "unitprice":"85000"                but i get just value of the fields like: "85000"                                                                                              how i can get  fieldname?                                                                                        thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code is constructing an array, when you seem to want a JSON Object.
Your question is too vague to be answered, but you can look at [this library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to manipulate JSON.